# Extract string after another string in a complicated string

Tags: javascript

I have this string -

```
ContactTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0032200000AYK5AAAX; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Spouse Cannot be more than 1: []

Class.ContactTriggerHelper.updateDependentData: line 309, column 1
Trigger.ContactTrigger: line 26, column 1
```

---

I need to identify if this string contains FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION and I need to extract this part of the message 'Spouse Cannot be more than 1'

Which I am not able to

I tried this --

```
      var pageErrors = saveResult.error[0].pageErrors[0].message;
                     console.log('pageErrors--->'+pageErrors);
                    var errMessage;
                    if(pageErrors.includes('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION')){
                        console.log('Inside includes');
                        console.log('pageErrors.indexOf("FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION")-->'+pageErrors.indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'));
                        console.log('pageErrors.lastIndexOf("FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION")-->'+pageErrors.lastIndexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,'));
                        errMessage = pageErrors.substring(pageErrors.indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'),pageErrors.lastIndexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,'));
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,\s*([^:]+)
```

[image]

```js
let findValue = (str) => {
  return str.match(/FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,\s*([^:]+)/i)
}

let str = `ContactTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0032200000AYK5AAAX; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Spouse Cannot be more than 1: []

Class.ContactTriggerHelper.updateDependentData: line 309, column 1 Trigger.ContactTrigger: line 26, column 1`

console.log(findValue(str))
console.log(findValue(str)[1])

let str2 = `ContactTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0032200000AYK5AAAX;

Class.ContactTriggerHelper.updateDependentData: line 309, column 1 Trigger.ContactTrigger: line 26, column 1`

console.log(findValue(str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do something simpler and faster than regular expressions. Since you **know the exact error message** you need to track, you can split the error string **from end of the error massage up to end of line or up to `":"` character** (you can also optionally trim it if you need to remove any surrounding spaces).

So:

```js
const str = `ContactTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0032200000AYK5AAAX; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Spouse Cannot be more than 1: []

Class.ContactTriggerHelper.updateDependentData: line 309, column 1 Trigger.ContactTrigger: line 26, column 1`;

const ERR = 'FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,';
const ind = str.indexOf(ERR);
let msg = -1 < ind ? str.slice(ind+ERR.length, str.indexOf("\n",ind+ERR.length)) : null;
msg = msg ? msg.trim() : null; // optionally trim it as well
console.log(str);
console.log(msg);
```